# Looking for non-Earth GIS Web Services

Tags: web-mapping, web-service, exogeography

Hey I'm building a web application and want to use some GIS services for other planets/moons.

In general, I want to find GIS web resources which apply to bodies apart from Earth.

Anybody have url endpoints to a:

- Mars tile service
- Titan WMS service
- Jupiter's Red Spot place finder
- Milky Way routing service
- Pluto geocoder

I'm more interested in services on the web, rather than data I would need to download and tile/host myself.

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Answer (score 2):

When US government sites are available again (shut down as of October 2013), try [PIGWAD](http://webgis.wr.usgs.gov/), Planetary Interactive G.I.S.-on-the-Web Analyzable Database at http://webgis.wr.usgs.gov. You can get an idea of its capabilities by checking a cached version via Google or the [Wayback Machine](http://www.archive.org).

Answer (score 1):

For Mars, you could check [JMARS](http://jmars.asu.edu/) and [google mars](http://www.google.com/mars/).